# Load data only once on the RAM using Python

Tags: numpy, python-import

Hopefully someone can help me. I have a set of static data files to do some data analysis, however, every time I run my script it takes really long time to see what is happening, because the data is loaded every time. Is there a way to load the data once and after just work with the data??
I have been using Jupyter notebooks and it work really well, but I would like a way to fix this problem by using Python code.

The sequence of my code is:
File 1: contains all the functions;
File 2: Contains all the variables and it calls file 1 in order to know what to do with the data.\n

**File 1** = functions.py\n

```
import numpy as np
def dict_files(filepath_lst):
   dictoffiles = {}
   for namefile in filepath_lst:
       content_file = np.loadtxt(namefile)
       dictoffiles[namefile] = content_file
## Sorting files according to smallest timestamp to largest##
   sorted_dictoffiles = {keys: values for keys, values in sorted(dictoffiles.items(), key=lambda    item: item[1][0, 0])}
   return sorted_dictoffiles
```

**File 2**\n

```
import functions as f
### ----------File Path -----------###
directory = 'some_file_path'
file_path = glob.glob(filejoin(directory, '*.dat'))
dictionary_of_files = f.dict_files(file_path)
```

Comment: Data gets loaded into the memory belonging to the process that loaded it. If you restart the script, you need to reload the data. The only alternative I can think of is a piece of shared memory that you get from a process that loads the data once and runs in the background forever.

Comment: I get it! Do you know if there is a way of working with Jupyter notebooks on a shared manner?? Like, I did all my methods using Jupyter, is there a way that other people can use it with their own data??